# Cassandra sometimes throws unauthorized error

Tags: python, cassandra, unauthorized

We have a multi-node Cassandra cluster and  we use Cassandra python driver for our insert queries. Everything was fine till we removed one of our nodes from the cluster using following command:

```
nodetool removenode force
```

Now our driver meets following error not always but once in a while:

```
(<class 'cassandra.Unauthorized'>, Unauthorized(u'code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="User username has no MODIFY permission on <table keyspace.tablename> or any of its parents"',), <traceback object at 0x7fe2447910e0>)
```

We use same user for all our insert queries and it has all required permissions.

What is our cluster's problem?

More info:
Cassandra version 3.0.0
Python driver version 3.0.0

Comment: It looks, the problem is not related with the Python driver. Is there any similar problems when login via csqlsh ?. Try to login via csqlsh and see how it goes.

Comment: @radkris The problem occurs in cqlsh too. I login with superuser but sometimes queries throws unauthorized error.

Comment: Ok, then the problem might not be just related with a particular driver or environment. As per the error message (User username has no MODIFY permission on <table keyspace.tablename> or any of its parents" ), it looks the problem is just happening only with some tables.  Is that correct ?. If it 's just happening only with some tables. then, this could be a consistency issue and repair might help.

Comment: @radkris It happends on diffrent tables. I ran repair command. It takes few days to complete. I'll check it after repair.

Comment: @radkris After repair the errors are gone. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you forced a remove node data may now be inconsistent you should start with a repair on the `system_auth` keyspace.

I would then follow up with a full repair of all the other keyspaces.